# Date syntax CHECK constraint in CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I am creating the table in SQLite and want to CHECK the syntax of the date. It should be 'YYYY-MM-DD'. When I insert data into this table it should give me error when I type something else when inserting the date, e.g. Insert into Member(DoB) values('2013-120qw'). It should be only for instance '2013-12-04'.

### Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE Member(
    email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    DoB TEXT(10) NOT NULL CHECK (length(DoB) IN (10) AND date(DoB) BETWEEN date('1900-01-01') AND date(CURRENT_DATE)),
    telephone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL CHECK (length(telephone) IN (11)),
    PRIMARY KEY (email)
);
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't implement check constraints anyway, so don't bother.  If you really need to check values, you need to use triggers.

Comment: What about in SQLite?

Comment: . . https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html.  The answer is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `date()` returns NULL for invalid date strings, and NULL does not make the check constraint fail.

Add a separate check that `date()` is happy:

```
...
DoB TEXT(10) NOT NULL CHECK (date(DoB) IS NOT NULL AND
                             length(DoB) = 10 AND
                             DoB BETWEEN '1900-01-01' AND CURRENT_DATE),
...
```

Comment: The NOT NULL before CHECK constraint doesn't it mean that it cannot be NULL?

Comment: `date('blah')` returns NULL.

Comment: You used date data type. I am using different data type is TEXT or VARCHAR. So if you input `DoB('blah')` return _blah_.

Comment: `date()` is a [function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), not a data type.

Comment: well, I did not ask you for the date() function. My DoB is a string not a function. If I could use date function I would not ask this question.

Comment: The code in my answer is tested and *works*. What is the specific problem that you have with it?

Comment: I tested your code and it does not work. I can insert any string in DoB and will work. It cannot allow the user to insert any string into date, date must be 'YYYY-MM-DD' but I can insert 'blahblahla' and will work, which is not what I want.

Comment: This SQLite, not MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

i thank DATE type is useful because MySql doesn't have Constraints

```
CREATE TABLE Member(
email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
DoB date NOT NULL,
telephone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL CHECK (length(telephone) IN (11)),
PRIMARY KEY (email)
```

);

if you need help this link will help you 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html